# How would I get list of all existing Flow Names/Labels within an org?

Tags: soql, visual-workflow

I would like to access all of the existing Flow Names/Labels that are available for the current user within an org. Is there any way to use a SOQL Query to get access to the names of all existing Flows that a user has access to? I am working on an aura component and want the names of all of the Flows that the user has access to for my component. I need it to be accessible in the Helper.js file for my Aura Component.

Edit: I have a text field where users input the name of the Flow they would like to select and go on from there. However, if the Flow name is incorrect, the flow displays an error. Rather than having the flow display an error, I want to make sure the flow exists first before starting the flow and handle the situation where the flow name does not exist. I wanted to get the Flow names first so that I could validate within the Helper JS file. I would really appreciate it if there was another solution to this.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 2):

Use this below query :-

SELECT Id, Label, ProcessType FROM FlowDefinitionView